# How to compute a big number modulo x?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I still have problems computing (without a calculator) for example:
$R_{21}(3^{234})$

I know i have to use the chinese reminder theorem, bu before that, how do i get there? I know that i haw to split 21 into primes, e.g. $3*7$, and therefor
$R_{3*7}((3^{39})^6)=..$.

I hope someone can briefly explain this to me with the given example, would be happy!

Thank you.

Comment: i need to compute it by hand, without a calculator, with the rules of number theory

Comment: For computation by hand see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand.